# In an Excel spreadsheet with my work schedule, is there a good way to format cells where I take Saturdays and Sundays off?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

For any rows that I have the weekend off, I just write 'Weekend' unless it's a column with headers'Temp(High)' or 'Temp(Low)'. Is there a better way to indicate a weekend instead of just writing it in? Or maybe leaving the field blank automatically can set it to say Weekend?

I've tried adding comments, but that's really it. It's a really simple excel sheet for record keeping, so it's not terribly important. I'd love to hear ideas and suggestions. :) It's in a long data style. All the columns in which I write weekend in cells are 'Time Left for Work,'Time Arrived','Fast Parking', and 'Weather'. Maybe I should just leave a comment in the 'Date' column I have in column A?

Comment: Post few of your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a date in A2, `=WEEKDAY($A2,2)>5` will evaluate to `TRUE` if Saturday or Sunday, or `FALSE` if Monday through Friday.

Therefore, `=IF(WEEKDAY($A2,2)>5, "WEEKEND", "")` will display "WEEKEND" if A2 is Saturday or Sunday.